# Custom EL function

Tags: jsp, el, jsp-tags

When creating a custom tag we can simply define them as follows:

1. Define them in `/WEB-INF/tags/widget/sample1.tag` or `/WEB-INF/tags/widget/sample2.tag`
2. import and use them in your jsp as `<%@ taglib prefix="w" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/widget"%>`
3. use them as `<w:sample/>` or `<w:sample2/>`

No need to define them on any XML or TLD file. (I am using tomcat 7 and I think this is a JSP 2 feature.)

For defining a custom EL function, however, I find that the function should be defined in a TLD file as:

```
 <function>
        <name>randomColor</name> <!-- Will be used to call your El Function:   ${myTagLibrary:randomColor()} inside your JSP page -->
        <function-class>foo.RandomColorGenerator</function-class>
        <function-signature>String pickRandomColor()</function-signature>
    </function>
```

Is there any way we can define a function, without defining it in TLD file?

PS: The project doesn't use JSF.

Comment: If you have a recent version of EL you could use an application-scoped bean and a [method call](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el003.htm#GJHBZ).